# A set on a plane that interests every line by exactly two points

Tags: geometry, set-theory

How to prove that there exists a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 $ such that every line on this plane contains exactly 2 points at this set?

It must be a corollary of Zorn`s lemma.

Comment: Such a set would be parametrised by a (half-)circle, as you can see by rotating a line around one of the two points of $S$ that it contains.

Comment: Hmm. Zorn's lemma shows that there exists a set $S$ which is maximal subject to the condition that it intersects every line in at most two points...

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I don't see how this is relevant to OP's question. Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich, yes and how to prove that this set is OK or it is not true?

Comment: I don't know - wasn't claiming to have a solution...

Comment: I don't see how to easily do it via Zorn's Lemma directly. Can you use the well-order theorem? If so, there is a relatively straightforward inductive argument.

Comment: Actually, the argument is already written down over at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21470/subset-of-the-plane-that-intersects-every-line-exactly-twice).

Comment: @Stefan Messenger, thank you!

Comment: @StefanMesken the point was only to have a nice picture in mind, I didn't claim that this was a hint. On the other hand, Zorn's lemma seems to apply quite straightforwardly indeed.

Comment: @Alexey You are welcome. This theorem was actually the first application of choice that I've ever seen. Fond memories... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a two-point set. I believe it's still  a (classic) open problem whether such a set can be Borel, as all such subsets are usuall non-constructive (AC-based, most often transfinite recursion), see [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864199002321/1-s2.0-S0166864199002321-main.pdf?_tid=spdf-e8fd9e69-58ed-46f8-97de-7b491a4d68b2&acdnat=1519511216_0ac0ad386e62da7695e5ceeca3bb77a8) for more on $3$-point sets and related problems.